# Panda dataframe find row that are present for all possible value of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a dataframe with below columns

```
Id  Name  Date
1   A     01-01-2020
2   B     01-01-2020
3   C     01-01-2020
4   D     01-01-2020
5   A     01-02-2020
6   B     01-02-2020
7   C     01-02-2020
8   D     01-02-2020
9   A     01-03-2020
0   C     01-03-2020
```

I am trying to find all **names** that are present in every **date**.
I was able to do it using csv python library by first finding all unique dates and then checking whether each name is present in all date or not.
In the above example only name **A** and **C** and present for all dates.
I wanted to know if its directly doable via panda dataframe or not maybe using groupby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us do `nunique` with `groupby`

```
n=df.Date.nunique()
s=df.groupby('Name').Date.nunique().eq(n)
s.index[s]
Index(['A', 'C'], dtype='object', name='Name')
```

Comment: thanks, this solves the problem. Could you explain more about the line s.index[s]

Comment: @ashley s is to get the number of unique date per Name, is the number is much the total unique date, we should pick that one up